# Linux timerfd> calling a function every x seconds without blocking the code execution

Tags: c, linux, timer

Need to call a function every X (let's say 5) seconds and the below code does it.

But it is blocking the execution of code. As I want it to work like `setitimer()`, where I can (for example) call a function every 5 sec and do something else.

```
   #include <sys/timerfd.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdint.h>        /* Definition of uint64_t */

   #define handle_error(msg) \
           do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       struct itimerspec new_value;
       int max_exp, fd;
       struct timespec now;
       uint64_t exp, tot_exp;
       ssize_t s;

       if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == -1)
           handle_error("clock_gettime");

       /* Create a CLOCK_REALTIME absolute timer with initial
          expiration and interval as specified in command line */

       new_value.it_value.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + 1; 
       new_value.it_value.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec;

       new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
       new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
       max_exp = 5; //say 5 times

       fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
       if (fd == -1)
           handle_error("timerfd_create");

       if (timerfd_settime(fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &new_value, NULL) == -1)
           handle_error("timerfd_settime");

       printf("timer started\n");
       for (tot_exp = 0; tot_exp < max_exp;) {
           s = read(fd, &exp, sizeof(uint64_t));
           if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
               handle_error("read");

           tot_exp += exp;
           printf("read: %llu; total=%llu\n",
                   (unsigned long long) exp,
                   (unsigned long long) tot_exp);
       }
    //Do something else ?
    //while(1);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

**EDIT**
I have one more question.
On changing these lines in above code from

```
   new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
   new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
```

to

```
   new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
   new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 5000000000;
```

I see that there is no 5 seconds delay. Whats happening here?

Comment: Execute that code in a new thread.

Comment: Thanks all.Added another question?

Comment: Depending on machine, could be overflow. long ints are only guaranteed 32 bits. Max for that is like 2 billion something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how to use multiplexing syscalls like [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the older `select(2)` which tends to become obsolete) and use them to test the readability of the file descriptor obtained by [timerfd_create(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) before `read(2)`-ing it.

However, be aware that `timerfd_create` works only when that `read` call succeeded. So only when the `poll` says you that the fd is not readable can you do something else. That something else should be quick (last less than 5 seconds).

You might want to investigate event loop libraries, like e.g. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) (wrapping `poll`). If you are coding a graphical application (using Qt or Gtk) it does already have its own event loop. If clever enough, you could do your 5-second period without any `timerfd_create`, just thru your event loop (by carefully setting the timeout given to `poll`, etc.).

#### Addenda:

the `tv_nsec` field should always be non-negative and less than 1000000000 (the number of nanoseconds in a second).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you have to use timerfd? Just schedule an alarm and make a handler for SIGALRM to call your function.

If you don't want to use signals, just create an extra thread to block on your timer fd and proceed as normal in the main thread.

If you don't like either of those and you want to do work while you're waiting, you have to poll. You can do it as basile suggests, or you could just store the current time and check whenever you would poll to see if the desired period has elapsed.

Comment: I didn't want to deal with Signals.

Comment: Signals across threads and handling the same ,race conditions etc . So i thought why not try the non signal way. Whats the advantage here ?

Comment: Threads are pretty much essential for anything that requires waiting for events while doing other computation.  Other than splitting computation between cores, this is their major primary use. If not, you're back to polling.

Comment: I agree with threads ,I was asking the advantage of using Signal based code like setitimer.

Comment: Signals are nicer for simple things this (imo). Basically, when the signal arrives, your main thread will be switched out and you'll enter the signal handler context. This will run until it is done and then control resumes in the main thread. You don't have to worry about getting switched back and forth while the signal handler is running.

Comment: @sshannin The problem is that there is not a lot you can do safely in a signal handler. You cannot e.g use printf(), accessing shared/global variables is very hard to get right, and often impossible. You cannot call malloc(), free() and many, many other things.

Comment: I certainly agree. I think we all know the dangers of non-reentrant functions...He didn't really indicate the scope of what he would do in the other function, so I started my suggestion off with the simplest answer (imo). As I say though, threads are also a fine solution if your requirements make rolling your own synchronization not worthwhile.